# How to set the default theme for new SubSites?

Tags: 2007, theme

I have a SiteCollection with custom themes. All the sites in the collection have a custom theme selected (MyTheme). Every time when I create a new subsite, the theme for that new site is the default theme and not the theme of the parent site.

How do I set the default theme for new subsites?

(I'm using MOSS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have a feature which programmatically applies your custom theme, and staple this feature to the site definition at the site collection level.

This means that every subsite that's created from the site definition within your site collection will automatically activate the feature and run your code to apply the theme.

Some links to help:

http://www.novolocus.com/2008/10/17/programmatically-apply-a-default-theme-in-sharepoint/

http://sridharu.blogspot.com/2008/07/change-site-theme-programatically.html

http://www.nnihlen.com/blog/archive/2006/12/04/724.aspx

http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/introduction-to-sharepoint-feature-stapling-part-1

http://e-junkie-chronicles.blogspot.com/2011/04/feature-stapling-tldr-version.html